# How does K2 Custom HTML module differ from Joomla's?

Tags: module, k2, joomla-3.5, custom-module

I know there's a K2 Tool's module and it has among other things, its own Custom HTML module. The only difference that I've noticed is that it has a "Parse PHP code" option.
So my question is...  is the K2 Custom HTML module different to the Joomla custom module in any other way? Are there any situations where you would choose one module over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used K2's Custom HTML module, but I would not suggest installing the entire K2 package just to be able to use this module. That's extremely overkill.

You best bet is to install the [Sourcerer](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer) plugin by **Regular Labs** (*formerly known as **NoNumber***). It allows you to add any of the following to your Joomla articles and custom HTML modules:

- Any kind of HTML
- CSS
- Javascript
- PHP

You simply need to wrap your PHP code in the `{source}` tags like so:

```
{source}
<?php
    echo 'Welcome to my Joomla! site';
?>
{/source}
```